# Can't read from /proc/self/attr/current, but permissions are 0666

Tags: linux, debian, selinux, kubernetes

I'm working with an externally created script that reads from /proc/self/attr/current to get SELinux configuration info.  It seems that, even though permissions on the file are `0666`, on some systems this file can be read with no problem while on others generate an "invalid argument" error.  Specifically, there is 1 server out of 3 in a Kubernetes cluster where this file cannot be read, while on the other 2 it contains the string "unconfined".

I came across [this thread](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18343) which reported the same issue without resolution.

What could be preventing this file from being read?

OS is Debian 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/[pid]/attr/current` provides the current security attributes for the process. This isn't necessarily SELinux; it is also used by AppArmor.

In the case of Debian systems, it almost certainly is AppArmor, as SELinux is rarely or never used on Debian.

In particular, the bare string `unconfined` also indicates it's AppArmor; SELinux would have a much longer "unconfined" string, such as `unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023`.

When this path can't be read, neither SELinux nor AppArmor is enabled.

Comment: Looks like that was it.  I was looking for SELinux configs and didn't consider AppArmor.  It turns out AppArmor wasn't installed on the one server but was on the other two.